# mod_rewrite add and switch directory

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

How to change the url pattern with mod_rewrite first from

```
domain.de/images/myfile.jpg
```

to

```
domain.de/directory/images/myfile.jpg
```

and then finally to

```
domain.de/images/directory/myfile.jpg
```

My rules so far

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.de$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/directory
RewriteRule ^(.*)$                                              directory/$1 [NC]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/directory\/images
RewriteRule ^\/directory\/images\/(.*)$                       images/directory/$1 [qsappend,L]
```

The first part is working but the exchange of directory fails

Answer (score 0):

After processing the second rewrite rule the first rewrite rule gets into an endless loop. To interrupt I had to change the first rule to check if "directory" is part of the url at all, like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.de$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/directory\/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$                                              directory/$1 [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.de$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/directory/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$                                              directory/$1 [NC]
```

Note the RHS is `!^/directory/`, with the anchoring `^`.

(Is the HTTP_HOST check really necessary?  Can't you put this in the `VirtualHost` section for `domain.de`?)

The second rewrite need only be:

```
RewriteRule ^/(directory)/(images)/(.*) /$2/$1/$3 [QSA,L]
```

I don't think you need the `RewriteCond` in this clause; if the URI doesn't begin with /directory/images then the rule won't match, so the `RewriteCond` is redundant.